# Eclipse Make Error: The source directory XXX does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt

Tags: eclipse, cmake

Into Eclipse, I have create a new HelloWorld CMake project and it work fine:

```
    HelloWorld/
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── config.h.in
    └── HelloWorld.cpp
```

The goal is to add some directories like this:

```
    HelloWorld/  
        └── src  
            └── c  
                 ├── CMakeLists.txt
                 ├── config.h.in  
                 └── HelloWorld.cpp
```

In this case, Eclipse says me "Eclipse Make Error: The source directory XXX does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt".

I have try to change some parameters (nature, build directory into build builder settings, using -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" option ) into Eclipse whitout succes.

In command line, I can make the project.

Put CMakeLists.txt file into sub directory and build from Eclipse